# \tikz \draw[violet] (0,0) circle (rand+2) is an oval!

Tags: tikz-pgf, random

can someone please explain to me why I get an oval from this command?
thanks.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\tikz \draw[violet] (0,0) circle (rand+2);
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: i reproduce your problem. try the following syntax: `\tikz \draw (0,0) circle[radius=2+rand];`. apparently with yours it take two radius as are defined for `elipse`.

Comment: Weird! First time I tried this I did get a circle but every time since, with and witout Zarkio's suggestion I get an ellipse. In any case, can you please expand the code snippets that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, include any necessary packages and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: @Zarko actually that was my first attempt. :) The problem persists.

Comment: By giving a unit of measurement to the radius, we get a circle: `\tikz \draw[violet] (0.0) circle (rand+2 cm);`

Comment: @AndréC that's very odd to me! it seems like you are right though. However, I thought that there is a default unit (cm) so why specifying a unit would solve this?

Comment: @AndréC  Quote, `pgfmanual.pdf` about `circle`: " The `<value>` may either be a dimension or a dimensionless number." And I  can get an ellipse with that syntax, but it won't be very visible because I think (but I'm not sure) in `number + dimension`, `number` is interpreted as a dimension in points.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can't really explain *why*, but if I were to hazard a guess I'd say that as `radius` sets both `x radius` and `y radius`, perhaps due to bad timing they get *different* random numbers, and you end up with an ellipse.

A workaround seems to be to save the value in a macro first with `\pgfmathsetmacro`, and use that instead.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}    
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines,step=0.5] (-3,-3) grid (3,3);

\pgfmathsetmacro{\bla}{rand+2}
\draw[violet] (0,0) circle[radius=\bla];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you already was aware of this, and was only interested in the "why", I can delete this answer.

Comment: I was aware of this, but there is no need for deletion I suppose. :) thanks anyway.

Comment: this seems to be a bug or some misconception how the radius is determined in macro.

Comment: @Aria I edited my answer with a theory, which may be total nonsense or a plausible explanation.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. your answer seems reasonable. AndréC workaround baffles me though :D it works and contradicts your guest I suppose.

Comment: @Aria I don't think Andre's workaround actually works (it didn't, in my tests), it just masks the problem. See the comment I wrote in answer to him.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. yeah. you are right. after 20 tests I produced an oval. :D